# inputs with width 100% have different sizes (submit, text, textarea)

Tags: html, css

I'm using html form inputs on my page (`text, textarea, submit`) to create a contact form, and I want to do some custom styling using css.

I've set the width of my inputs to 100%, but somehow the button input(submit) ends up being smaller than the textarea and text inputs. I can't really figure out what's going on here.

How do I get them to be all the same size (I need to use % values, want to make my site responsive)?

Snippet below, missing the main .css file since it's not relevant to the question. Ionicons.css is a custom icons fonts, that I use on other parts of this page, and I've linked normalize.css from a CDN.

Thanks for the help.

```css
/************************************************
TEXT, BOX...
************************************************/
.contact-box {
 background-color: #e3f9ec;
 padding: 1em;
}
.contact-box p {
 margin-bottom: 0.5em;
 padding: 0;
}



/************************************************
INPUTS
************************************************/
input, textarea {
 margin: 1em auto;
 width: 100%;
}
input[name="name"], input[name="email"] {
}
textarea[name="msg"] {
 height: 10em;
 resize: none;
}
input[type="submit"] {
 background-color: #913D88;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <title> Contact | PTC Testers
</title>

      <meta name="description" content="Pay to click sites testing">
      <meta name="author" content="Shooshte">

      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contact.css">
      
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
        <h1>PTCTesters<small>.com</small></h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php/articles">articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php/sites">sites</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php/contact">contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php/login">login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div id="content">
       <div class="contact-box">
  <p>Please don't hesitate to drop us an email with any questions, suggestions, party invitations or anything else.</br><br/>Please enter a valid email in order to receive a response. We try our best to reply in the shortest time possible.<br/><br/>Have a nice day!</p>
     <form action="" method="post">
      <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name or username"></br>
      <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email address"></br>
         <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea></br>
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="send">
     </form>
 </div>
    </div>
      
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <footer>
      &copy;&nbsp;PTC-Testers,&nbsp;2015
    </footer> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: All elements have default CSS attributed to them. Without looking into the developer tools, I'd assume the `textarea` element has more default padding than the `input[type=submit]`.

Comment: tried setting `padding:0` on all three, problem still there

Comment: use http://cssreset.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of form elements have default padding and border styles, it may vary depending on different browser and OS. Apply [`box-sizing:border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) can make them to be truly 100% size.

```
input, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
/************************************************
TEXT, BOX...
************************************************/
.contact-box {
 background-color: #e3f9ec;
 padding: 1em;
}
.contact-box p {
 margin-bottom: 0.5em;
 padding: 0;
}



/************************************************
INPUTS
************************************************/
input, textarea {
 margin: 1em auto;
 width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[name="name"], input[name="email"] {
}
textarea[name="msg"] {
 height: 10em;
 resize: none;
}
input[type="submit"] {
 background-color: #913D88;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <title> Contact | PTC Testers
</title>

      <meta name="description" content="Pay to click sites testing">
      <meta name="author" content="Shooshte">

      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contact.css">
      
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
        <h1>PTCTesters<small>.com</small></h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php/articles">articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php/sites">sites</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php/contact">contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php/login">login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div id="content">
       <div class="contact-box">
  <p>Please don't hesitate to drop us an email with any questions, suggestions, party invitations or anything else.</br><br/>Please enter a valid email in order to receive a response. We try our best to reply in the shortest time possible.<br/><br/>Have a nice day!</p>
     <form action="" method="post">
      <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name or username"></br>
      <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email address"></br>
         <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea></br>
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="send">
     </form>
 </div>
    </div>
      
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <footer>
      &copy;&nbsp;PTC-Testers,&nbsp;2015
    </footer> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
input, textarea{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

to keep your padding's inside the element. The inputs' and textarea's padding's are pushing the width beyond 100%. Alternatively, set

```
input, textarea{
    width: Calc(100% - 4px); // 4px = cumulated lateral padding
}
input.button{
     width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
/************************************************
TEXT, BOX...
************************************************/
.contact-box {
 background-color: #e3f9ec;
 padding: 1em;
}
.contact-box p {
 margin-bottom: 0.5em;
 padding: 0;
}



/************************************************
INPUTS
************************************************/
input, textarea {
 margin: 1em auto;
 width: 100%;
 border-left-width: 2px;
 border-right-width: 2px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
}
input[name="name"], input[name="email"] {
}
textarea[name="msg"] {
 height: 10em;
 resize: none;
}
input[type="submit"] {
 background-color: #913D88;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <title> Contact | PTC Testers
</title>

      <meta name="description" content="Pay to click sites testing">
      <meta name="author" content="Shooshte">

      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contact.css">
      
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
        <h1>PTCTesters<small>.com</small></h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php/articles">articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php/sites">sites</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php/contact">contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC_php/login">login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div id="content">
       <div class="contact-box">
  <p>Please don't hesitate to drop us an email with any questions, suggestions, party invitations or anything else.</br><br/>Please enter a valid email in order to receive a response. We try our best to reply in the shortest time possible.<br/><br/>Have a nice day!</p>
     <form action="" method="post">
      <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name or username"></br>
      <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email address"></br>
         <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea></br>
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="send">
     </form>
 </div>
    </div>
      
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <footer>
      &copy;&nbsp;PTC-Testers,&nbsp;2015
    </footer> 
  </body>
</html>
```